# Read HTML elements

Tags: javascript, firefox, xhtml, firefox-addon, xul

I'm building an Firefox Add-On That is suposed to read all  in the HTML doc.

My problem is: I Can't make my JS in XUL read the HTML elements inside the HTML document.

I already tried

```
content.document.getElementsByTagName('a')
```

And

```
document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('a')
```

What am I doing Wrong?

Comment: I'm assuming you have JavaScript that you've included in a `browser.xul` that's overlaying the browser window, right?

Comment: What lwburk said, and also, you should make sure your script runs after the browser window is loaded, rather than just running immediately.

Comment: I'm running in a index.xul.  My Js functions is only called when in the onclick event. This event is called by an Button that I put in the Statusbar.

Comment: `content.document.getElementsByTagName('a')` should work, what result(s) are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `window.content.getElementsByTagName('a')` and `window._content.getElementsByTagName('a')` ?

MDC sais `_content` is deprecated and you should use the first one.

If it's not working, I would say the problem is somwhere else.

Comment: I finally got it working. At first i Used .content, But then I installed jQuery at my XUL Extension and now it's even easier to access the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery is easy -

First add it to your overlay.xul

```
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://parentalcontrolbs/content/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" />
```

Than access DOM code using:

Ex:

```
    doc = content.document;
    $("a:contains(flamengo)", doc).html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this:

```
window.opener.content.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
```

This is working in my extension.
Good luck!